Cannot get IK armiture to bend its knee correctly
My Armature model is a biped creater that has 4 bones per leg. thigh,calf, foot and then an IK bone.
I have the x and y axis locked but as you can see with the blue line the z axis should allow the knee to move in the right direction.  However If you look in the picture the blue line show it should allow the knee to bend like a human knee. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here's the blend file.  The right leg when you are looking at the cannon head on is the one with the axis locks.


sorry, without knowing what you did and just an image - this isn't enough information to help you. So please provide blend file so we can check it out on our own. thx.

Please share the file: https://blend-exchange.com/

You could create a controller behind the foot, parent the foot to the controller, create a pole target in front of the knee, parent these 2 bones to the root bone of your armature, give an IK constraint to the calf with the controller as Target and the poletarget as Pole Target, change the Pole Angle if necessary:

